# Using Jsoniq to display some of the string in json

Tags: javascript, json, xquery, jsoniq

Can you guys teach me on how to use jsoniq to display both of the book name which is robin cruose and tom jones?  i've gone through some research but no matter how i do, it's always wrong.

```js
{
   "books": {
      "reader": {
         "Read": {
            "book": {
               "name": "Robinson Crusoe",
               "author": "Daniel Defoe"
            }
         },
         "HaventRead": {
            "book": {
               "name": " Tom Jones",
               "author": "Henry Fielding "
            }
         },
         "_type": "Ken Rawing"
      }
   }
}
```

This is how i did in zorba.io and it got lots of error, i am very sure the way i did is totally wrong. Please teach me

```js
for $reader in collection("books"),
$read in collection("books"),
$book in collection ("books")
where $reader.type eq "Ken Rawing"
return $book
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting some leaf values from a JSON document is done with the navigation syntax, which is the `.` notation.

It doesn't need a `for` clause, as iteration is implicit with the `.`.

Assuming the object is stored in the variable `$content`, `$content.books.reader` navigates to the object with the fields `Read` and `HaventRead`. Calling `jnlib:values()` then gets the two objects in there, and then one continues all the way to the name with `.book.name`.

The query is like so (most of it is actually the input document itself, which is typically stored in a file or a data store instead):

```
jsoniq version "1.0";

import module namespace jnlib = "http://jsoniq.org/function-library";

(: That's the input document, stored in a global variable :)
declare variable $content := {
   "books": {
      "reader": {
         "Read": {
            "book": {
               "name": "Robinson Crusoe",
               "author": "Daniel Defoe"
            }
         },
         "HaventRead": {
            "book": {
               "name": " Tom Jones",
               "author": "Henry Fielding "
            }
         },
         "_type": "Ken Rawing"
      }
   }
};

(: That's the query :)
jnlib:values($content.books.reader).book.name
```

Mind the `jsoniq version="1.0";`, which activates the native JSONiq parser (the default parser on `try.zorba.io` is XQuery).

It can also be tested in [zorba.io](http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/BhSvzsG3EMcbbGK0OGKc2sEBjAs%3D)

#### Note

JSONiq also exists as an extension to XQuery, in which case navigation is done with function calls, as the `.` is a valid character in XML names. However, it is **not** recommended to use this unless you have XML to deal with as well.

```
jnlib:values($content("books")("reader"))("book")("name")
```